# select.select() isn't accepting my socket and returns empty lists

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, select

I wished to write a script for something that would act as both a server and a client. For the server part I decided I should create an SSL socket `accept()` loop that would listen to new connections forever, and to make it non-blocking so that the client part can work I decided to use `select`.

Here's the script:

```
from socket import (socket, 
                    AF_INET, 
                    SOCK_STREAM, 
                    create_connection, 
                    SOL_SOCKET, 
                    SO_REUSEADDR)
from ssl import (SSLContext, 
                 PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER, 
                 PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)


import select

import threading

import time
from tqdm.auto import tqdm


            

def handle_client(client, address):
    request_bytes = b"" + client.recv(1024)

    if not request_bytes:
        print("Connection closed")
        client.close()
    request_str = request_bytes.decode()
    print(f"we've received {request_str}")



ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8443
server_context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
server_context.load_cert_chain('cert_ex1.pem', 'key_ex1.pem')


initial_counter = 1


server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((ip, port))
server_socket.listen(5)



print("forming lists for select...")
inputs = [server_socket]
print(f"we now have list inputs: {inputs}")
outputs = []

while True:
    print(f"checking: inputs still has a single socket in it: {type(inputs[0])}")
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, 1)
    print(f"readable is {readable}, \n writable is {writable}, \n exceptional is {exceptional}")
    for s in tqdm(readable):
        if s is server_socket:
            print("wrapping server socket in SSL...")
            with server_context.wrap_socket(server, server_side=True) as tls:
                connection, client_address = tls.accept()
                print("making the connection non-blocking...")
                connection.setblocking(0)
                inputs.append(connection)
                print("starting a thread that'd handle the messages...")
                threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(connection, client_address)).start()                
            
        else:
            print(f"dealing with socket {s}")

        
hostname='example.org'
client_context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
client_context.load_verify_locations('cert_ex1.pem')


with create_connection((ip, port)) as client:
    with client_context.wrap_socket(client, server_hostname=hostname) as tls:
        print(f'Using {tls.version()}\n')
        print("client is sending data...")
        tls.sendall(int.to_bytes(initial_counter, 4, 'little'))

        while True:
            data = tls.recv(1024*8)
            if not data:
                print("Client received no data")
                break
            
            new_data = int.from_bytes(data, 'little')
            print(f'Server says: {new_data}')
            new_data = int.to_bytes(new_data+1, 4, 'little')
            print("sleeping for 0.15...")
            time.sleep(0.15)
            tls.sendall(new_data)
```

The problem with running this script is that it creates the socket properly, passes a list with just this socket to `select.select()`, but then `select()` returns 3 empty lists.

1. Is there a reason for this?
2. Is there anything else wrong with my code (the general idea, trying to make this work with SSL, using `connection.setblocking(0)`, anything else)?

Comment: You'll probably have a worse time with non-blocking sockets than you'd have with e.g. `SocketServer` or just doing a thread-per-client by hand...

Comment: @AKX: 1) which `SocketServer` do you mean? 2) what exactly do you mean?

Comment: (1) [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver). (2) When a client connects, spawn a thread to talk to that socket exclusively. Then you don't need to `select` to find out which sockets have interesting material, because the thread can just block.

Comment: 1) got it, thanks
2) In the current scenario, I create a socket which listens for connections indefinitely, and `select` tells me if there are any; if I don't use `select`, how do I get to know that a client has connected?

Comment: (2) You block on `accept()`.

Comment: 2) That's kind of the point: suppose a write a classic loop: `while True: connection, address = tls.accept()`, it would indeed block on `accept()`. I run the script, I get to this loop, and it blocks forever, never getting to the point where I can get to do anything else, specifically connect to a socket (in this example to itself). 
I should also point out that all of this, while interesting, doesn't address the issue with `select()` the OP is about

Comment: Blocking on `accept()` is only an issue for a toy program that acts both as a server and a client. A solution is to start your client as a thread before you block on `accept()` (or alternatively `accept()` in a thread). These would be simpler to work with than non-blocking sockets and `select()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256832/discussion-between-chiffa-and-akx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using non-blocking sockets on the server side – the client is still spawned into a different thread, but that's done in the "idle callback", so now you can see you can accept clients and client data and still occasionally do other work in the same program.

I skipped the `ssl` bits because I don't have your certs at hand, but be sure to only wrap both sockets once...

```
import random
import select
import socket
import threading
import time

hostname = "example.org"
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8443
client_counter = 0


def server(idle_callback):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((ip, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    # server_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    # server_socket = server_context.wrap_socket(server_socket, server_side=True)

    clients = []

    while True:
        sockets = [server_socket, *clients]
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(sockets, [], sockets, 0.1)
        for s in readable:
            if s is server_socket:
                connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
                connection.setblocking(False)
                clients.append(connection)
                print(f"new connection from {client_address}")
            else:  # must be a client socket
                try:
                    msg = s.recv(1024)
                    print(f"{s}: received {msg}")
                    if msg.startswith(b"The time is"):
                        s.sendall(b"The eagle flies at midnight...\n")
                    else:
                        s.sendall(f"Sorry, I don't understand {msg}\n".encode())
                except ConnectionError as exc:
                    print(f"{s}: {exc}")
                    s.close()
                    clients.remove(s)
                    continue
        for x in exceptional:
            print(f"exceptional condition on {x}")
            x.close()
            clients.remove(x)
        idle_callback()


def client():
    global client_counter
    client_counter += 1
    client_id = client_counter
    print(f"[{client_id}] Starting client...")

    with socket.create_connection((ip, port)) as client:
        # client_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
        # with client_context.wrap_socket(client, server_hostname=hostname) as client:
        #     print(f'Using {client.version()}\n')

        while True:
            if random.random() < 0.1:
                print(f"[{client_id}] Time to go...")
                break

            if random.random() < 0.5:
                client.sendall(f"The time is {time.asctime()}\n".encode("utf-8"))
            else:
                client.sendall(b"Hello, server\n")

            data = client.recv(1024 * 8)
            if not data:
                print(f"[{client_id}] Client received no data")
                break
            print(f"[{client_id}] Server says: {data}")
            time.sleep(0.5)


def idle_callback():
    if random.random() < 0.1:
        threading.Thread(target=client).start()


def main():
    server(idle_callback)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks. I'll spend some time studying it and come back with any question

Comment: *"I skipped the ssl bits ..."* - they are relevant though since they make it much more complex. With SSL it is possible that the socket is not readable in select, but one still could be read (pending data from a previously received TLS record). It is possible that the socket is readable but one cannot read anything (non-payload records like session tickets). It is possible that one need to check for writable even though one has no payload to write (sending session tickets) ...

Comment: _much_ more complex? Wouldn't the wrapped read just being short then if the only readable data had been a non-payload record?